# Get channel name in Redis messages on Node.js

Tags: node.js, redis, publish-subscribe

I am using Redis as a Pub/Sub client in a Node.js application.  I bind a subscriber to a channel pattern like thus:

```
client.psubscribe("events.*.new", (event) => console.log("NEW EVENT", event));
```

Then, I send a message on a specific channel this way:

```
client.publish("events.123.new", '{"some": "data"}');
```

In my terminal, I get the following output:

```
NEW EVENT null
```

My question is 2-fold:

1. Any reason why my data might end up being `null`?
2. Is there a way to access the full name of the channel over which a message has been sent?  Since I am listening on the pattern `events.*.new`, it does not appear that I can know if a message was sent on channel `events.123.new` or on `events.456.new`.  Is passing this information **within** the payload the only way to access it in listeners?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What nodejs library are you using for redis?

Comment: @BarışUşaklı I'm using NodeRedis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
client.psubscribe("events.*.new");

client.on('pmessage', function (pattern, channel, message) {
    console.log(pattern, channel, message);
});

client.publish("events.123.new", '{"some": "data"}');
```

The callback to psubscribe just returns error in the first argument if there is an error. You can find more info [here](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#subscriber-events)